# The MAX function in DAX only accepts a column reference as an argument

Tags: dax

I am new to DAX. Below is my code:

```
var maxdate = MAX((DATEADD(DimDate[Date], -1 , month)))
```

From research, DATEADD returns A table containing a single column of date values.

However, I get the following error when I try to save the measure *"The MAX function only accepts a column reference as an argument."* What is the name of the column in the table return by DATEADD so I can reference it.

Comment: What is this variable intended to return?

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for me:

```
VAR maxdate = LASTDATE ( DATEADD ( DimDate[Date],-1, MONTH ) )
```